# ExecuteScript returning null for boolean js variable

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Iam new to selenium . I am trying to call executescript but it returns null in place of a boolean value .

My JS code is as follows-

```
document.recordingComplete = false;
```

Java code-

```
public SeleniumDriverWrapper waitForCompletion(int pollFrequencySeconds) throws InterruptedException{

   boolean recordingStopped =  saveSession();
   return this;
}
public boolean saveSession(){
    return (Boolean)((JavascriptExecutor) webDriver).executeScript("return window.parent.document.recordingComplete");
}
```

Could any one help out why executescript returns null.

Comment: http://screencloud.net/v/62O8

Comment: Why are you referencing window.parent in your selenium script? Are you trying to escape a sandbox such as an iframe? The browser won't allow that.